# What is the difference between sinon stub.restore and stub.reset

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

When cleaning up, after creating a stub with sinon, you can restore or reset it. Can someone explain to me what the difference between these two are? Or when to use restore and when to use reset?

Answer (score 4):

When you have the following code:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(object, "foo");
```

The original `object.foo` method is gone. If you want to restore it, you can do `object.foo.restore()` or simply `stub.restore()` as a shortcut. In other terms, `restore` has an impact on `object`.

Whereas `stub.reset()` has an impact on `stub` itself, resetting both its behavior and its history. (cache data like how many times it has been called, previous calls…)